# Select from view only give me 5 rows when the table has many more

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm using SQLite in my iPhone app.

I tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1;
```

And the response contains 5 rows but the table has 30 rows; why does this happen?

Comment: How have you defined your table - and more importantly - how did you declare your `CREATE VIEW` statement?

Comment: Depends on how many rows your view has ... since you are actually selecting from view. You may have defined some condition in `create view` statement which restrict your view to have only 5 rows.